# Menu hover z-index error in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

(Solved)

If you look at this wip you'll see that the menu hover states doesn't overlay the content below, I have no idea why this is happening and I've tried adding z-index values to most parts of the ul tree, including the outer most nav tag -

http://staffanestberg.com/lesmarket2/product.php

What am I missing?

If it's easier here are the parts in particular -

```
<div id="menu-wrapper">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">New arrivals</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Designers</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Clothing</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shoes </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Accessories</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sale</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

header nav #menu-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 80;
  width: 625px;
  height: 31px;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent url(../images/stripe-menu.gif) no-repeat;
}
header nav #menu-wrapper a,
header nav #menu-wrapper a:active,
header nav #menu-wrapper a:visited,
header nav #menu-wrapper a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
header nav #menu-wrapper #menu {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 81;
  margin: 6px 0 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
header nav #menu-wrapper #menu li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 82;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
header nav #menu-wrapper #menu ul li:hover a,
header nav #menu-wrapper #menu li:hover li a {
  background: none;
}
header nav #menu-wrapper #menu li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
header nav #menu-wrapper #menu ul {
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  display: none;
  width: 140px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -15px;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 90;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}
header nav #menu-wrapper #menu ul li:first-child {
  border-top: 1px dotted #fff;
}
header nav #menu-wrapper #menu ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 18px;
}
header nav #menu-wrapper #menu:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
header nav #menu-wrapper html[xmlns] #menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Try always to post some test-case, shortened relevant code - for future generations

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to your `#menu-wrapper` a position: relative / absolute (what best suits) and a z-index

- IE7 likes when the most top parent has a z-index well defined to allow it's children to overlap other elements (with lower z-index)
- IE7 does not like the `rgba` (your `ul` elements) background color. Use a fallback color:

.

```
   header nav #menu-wrapper #menu ul{
       background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
       background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
       /* ... */
    }
```

Comment: Tried giving both the #menu-wrapper as well as the #menu a position and a z-index value, none of which solved the problem unfortunately. When you say the most top parent element, do you mean the outer most element that has an ID (such as #menu in this case)?

Comment: @Staffan That could be the one. Might be I did not followed well all the parents up the tree. Try with him and let me know the result

Comment: @Staffan Actually, after a second look - I think your elements ARE overlapping, just the background is missing. (I can see white text but no bg!) And to solve that issue change `rgba()` to `rgb()`

Comment: I see both the text and the background (#000) but they're not overlapping the content beneath (the product brand name for example). I might however, be doing a mistake - I'm comparing these browser differences with the IE9 built-in renderer, set up as IE7. Could this approach be missleading?

Reg. the background-color, it should either be showing a RGBA setting (if supported), or just a plain black background. That's really not the issue.

Comment: Really dunno. I gave you just some ideas. Please now I'm really interested in this issue. Let me know if you find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Np, thanks for all the suggestions. I'll let you know as soon as I have an answer.

Comment: May I give you another suggestion? try to remove from your CSS the `header nav` elements. You already point to '#' ID elements, so you don't need the extra leading `header nav` in your selector reference. THat are specific HTML5 elements, so IE might have some problems handling them.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for suggesting to check out the HTML5 elements. Although they were not the problem, for some reason giving the outer most (the header tag) a position of relative seems to have been causing the glitch.

Comment: Thanks @Staffan for sharing the info. I'll try to remember that one for the future (*Short life IE!* :) )

Comment: On second thought, it seems THIS is actually causing the error: http://jonathanstegall.com/2009/01/15/ie-z-index-bug-with-css-dropdown-menu/ Add a position: relative to the container below the menu and it should work.